# Sencha Studio tests on Windows 10 neither run in IDE nor via CLI

Tags: extjs, windows-10, command-line-interface, sencha-cmd

I'm new to Sencha and so for Sencha Test. On my Windows 10 machine I installed the latest Sencha Studio and imported a sample project for ours. Following tutorials I created a test suite with the sample "it should pass 1 = 1" test. But I cannot run this test, neither via IDE nor CLI.

On the scenario I selected my local Chrome browser and the sample test. When I click on RUN, the browser selection on the right gets updated with gray bullets or void but nothing else happens. Changing the scenario's test type to "Webdriver" or "In-browser" does not change anything in regard for the outcome.

I also tried to execute the test via CLI but no success either. I always end up with this message: "Sencha Test v2.0.2Error: Sencha Cmd install directory not found : C:\Users[MY_PROFILE]\bin\Sencha\Cmd." That's right, my Sencha Cmd installation is located in C:\dev\Sencha\Cmd and works properly. Where's the configuration to change that stc can find Sencha Cmd?

Any hints how to get the tests run? Is an archive server mandatory to run the tests? Is there anything that I might have missed? Using Google was no help so far.

Maybe that's helpful: The Event Recorder does also not work properly. When I click on recording, my Chrome does not get opened, I have to open it by myself and navigate to the URL provided by Sencha Studio. Weird.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of thinking and searching I think the most critical error was to NOT install Sencha Cmd and Sencha Test into the installer's recommended folder. I still have issues when starting tests but I'll post an answer if there's anything interesting about this topic.

Also, it seems that Sencha Test always expects that a built project exists. So just checking out the sources without building them is not sufficient to run tests, even if you're testing e.g. the staging.